# How to print the value of text box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have text box called "userInput" and one submit button.I want to print the value of the text box which is entered by user like a stack(previous values also,not just the current value).

any idea..??

```
<input type="text" name="userInput"/>
<input type="button" name="sub" value="submit">
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: You should post what you've attempted so far, rather than asking us to write your (pretty trivial) code for you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to have a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stack = [];

$("input [name=userInput]").change(function () { stack.push(this.value); });
```

You can change that event to blur, focus, etc. depending on when you want the values recorded.

Answer (score 0):

A submit button usually is for submitting a form. Submitting a form is sending a request to the server and refreshing the page. So in your server side script you could read the posted values and show them in the resulting page (you don't need javascript for this).

If you don't want to redirect you could handle the submit event and cancel the default submission:

```
var values = [];
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_form').submit(function() {
        // get the entered value:
        var userInput = $(':input[name=userInput]').val();

        // add the current value to the list
        values.push(userInput);

        // show the values
        alert(values.join(", "));

        // cancel the default submission
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AddToStack() {
            var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
            var stack = document.getElementById('stack');
            stack.innerHTML += '<p>' + userInput.value + '</p>';

            //clear input an refocus:
            userInput.value = '';
            userInput.focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stack"></div>
    <input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput"/>
    <button type="button" name="sub" onclick="AddToStack();">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ::Thnak for your reply.I want to print the value of text box using when click the submit button.

Comment: ::I want to pass the text box value using post method.So I surround <form></form> tags.Now It does not print the value of text box.

Any idea..??